# SQL Server Many to many on the same table how to join and query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following relationship between 2 table.

[image]

There is a many to many relationship between 2 tables.(2 foreign keys in BigGroups pointing to GroupId in Table Groups)

```
SELECT GroupName FROM Groups where GroupId IN
  (SELECT bg.AssociatedGroupId 
    FROM BigGroups bg INNER JOIN Groups g ON bg.GroupId=g.GroupId 
    WHERE bg.GroupId=@GroupId)
```

This query returns me what I am looking for but I believe there could be a better way of doing this(better performance). Or maybe I should change the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If I've read it right then you're looking for the GroupName of AssociatedGroups for the @GroupId parameter? This is a more concise query to achieve the same thing.

```
SELECT g.GroupName 
FROM BigGroups bg 
INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.GroupId = bg.AssociatedGroupId
WHERE bg.GroupId = @GroupId
```

Nothing wrong with that relationship, although I think it's 1-to-many; 1 group can have zero or more associated groups.